# removing a slider from a template in HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css, web, slider, css-transitions

I'm making modifications in a current template. There is a slider in the start of web page which needs to be removed. There are just two images with the slider. When user drags the image, the next image appears. And I want to remove this slider, and make image fixed so that it doesn't move. I have tried multiple things like making modifications to css class and removing class from the div but nothing works. Either the image gets removed or it starts appearing on the whole page.

Here is the **html** code:

```
        <div class="project-carousel-wrap fullheight">

            <div class="owl-carousel project-carousel fullheight">
               <!-- project-carousel-item -->
                <div class="fullheight img-bg">
   <!-- The mobile and desktop view works fine for which the lower divs are used -->

<!-- There was some if conditions that's why code is written inside php tags-->
<?php    
echo "<div class='mobile-image'>";
    echo "<img src='images/works/masonry/01p.jpg'>";     
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div class='desktop-image'>";
    echo "<img src='images/works/masonry/01.jpg'>";
    echo "</div>";
    ?>

</div>
          <!-- project-carousel-item-->
            <div class=" fullheight img-bg">
<?php
echo "<img src='images/works/masonry/01.jpg'>";
 ?>
            </div> </div>

    </div>
```

Here is the **CSS** code:

```
/* 
 *  Owl Carousel - Animate Plugin
 */
.owl-carousel .animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1000ms;
  animation-duration: 1000ms;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-animated-in {
  z-index: 1;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-animated-out {
  z-index: 1;
}
.owl-carousel .fadeOut {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeOut;
  animation-name: fadeOut;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

/* 
 *  Owl Carousel - Auto Height Plugin
 */
.owl-height {
  -webkit-transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;
  transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;
}

/* 
 *  Core Owl Carousel CSS File
 */
.owl-carousel {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  /* position relative and z-index fix webkit rendering fonts issue */
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-stage {
  position: relative;
  -ms-touch-action: pan-Y;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-stage:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-stage-outer {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;

  /* fix for flashing background */
 /* -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); */
}
.owl-carousel .owl-controls .owl-nav .owl-prev,
.owl-carousel .owl-controls .owl-nav .owl-next,
.owl-carousel .owl-controls .owl-dot {
 /* cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;*/
  display: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.owl-carousel.owl-loaded {
  display: block;
}
.owl-carousel.owl-loading {
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
}
.owl-carousel.owl-hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-refresh .owl-item {
  display: none;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-item {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  float: left;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-item img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
 /*
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  */
}
.owl-carousel.owl-text-select-on .owl-item {
  -webkit-user-select: auto;
  -moz-user-select: auto;
  -ms-user-select: auto;
  user-select: auto;
}
/*
.owl-carousel .owl-grab {
  cursor: move;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  cursor: -o-grab;
  cursor: -ms-grab;
  cursor: grab;
}
*/
.owl-carousel.owl-rtl {
  direction: rtl;
}
.owl-carousel.owl-rtl .owl-item {
  float: right;
}

/* No Js */
.no-js .owl-carousel {
  display: block;
}

/* 
 *  Owl Carousel - Lazy Load Plugin
 */
.owl-carousel .owl-item .owl-lazy {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease;
  -ms-transition: opacity 400ms ease;
  -o-transition: opacity 400ms ease;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-item img {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

/* 
 *  Owl Carousel - Video Plugin
 */
.owl-carousel .owl-video-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-video-play-icon {
  position: absolute;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -40px;
  margin-top: -40px;
  background: url("owl.video.play.png") no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: scale 100ms ease;
  -moz-transition: scale 100ms ease;
  -ms-transition: scale 100ms ease;
  -o-transition: scale 100ms ease;
  transition: scale 100ms ease;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-video-play-icon:hover {
  -webkit-transition: scale(1.3, 1.3);
  -moz-transition: scale(1.3, 1.3);
  -ms-transition: scale(1.3, 1.3);
  -o-transition: scale(1.3, 1.3);
  transition: scale(1.3, 1.3);
}
.owl-carousel .owl-video-playing .owl-video-tn,
.owl-carousel .owl-video-playing .owl-video-play-icon {
  display: none;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-video-tn {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: contain;
  -moz-background-size: contain;
  -o-background-size: contain;
  background-size: contain;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease;
  -ms-transition: opacity 400ms ease;
  -o-transition: opacity 400ms ease;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-video-frame {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

I'm stuck in this issue from quite a long while. As this is an ready made template that's why I'm not able to find where the issue is, and that's why I've posted all the css code. Any suggestions, modifications or solutions will be highly appreciated. I'll be happy to provide any other details if needed.

You can check the issue here:
[Project Link](https://ithinkimage.000webhostapp.com/project.php?a=7)

The main image in the start, when we drag it to left or right it moves. I would like to have it still and no movement. Thanks
Here is the **main.js** code:

```
/*global $:false */
/*global window: false */
(function() {
    "use strict";
    $(function($) {

        //Detecting viewpot dimension
        var vH = $(window).height();
        var vW = $(window).width();
        //Adjusting Intro Components Spacing based on detected screen resolution
        $('.fullwidth').css('width', vW);
        $('.fullheight').css('height', vH);
        $('.halfwidth').css('width', vW / 2);
        $('.halfheight').css('height', vH / 2);
        $('.90percheight').css('height', vH-vH/10);
        $('.ms-section img').css('max-width', vW / 2);
        //$('.slant-bg-wrap, .slant-layer:first-child:before').css('max-width', vW);

        //Equal Heights Trigger
        $('.equal-height-childs').equalHeights();

        //PRELOADER
        $('body, html').addClass('preloader-running');
        $('#mastwrap').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        $(window).load(function() {
            $("#status").fadeOut();
            $("#preloader").delay(1000).fadeOut(1000);
            $('body, html').removeClass('preloader-running');
            $('body, html').addClass('preloader-done');
            $("#mastwrap").delay(1000).css('visibility',
                'visible');
        });

        //Common UX/UI
        if ( $( "#works-container" ).length ) {
            $( ".works-filter-wrap" ).fadeIn(3000);
        }
        if ( $('.studio-approach-item').length ) {
            $('.studio-approach-item').on('click', function(){
                $('.studio-approach-item-details').slideUp();
                $('.studio-approach-item').removeClass('active-item');
                $(this).addClass('active-item');
                $(this).find('.studio-approach-item-details').slideDown();
            });
        }


        //Main Menu Trigger

        $('.menu-icon-wrapper, .mobile-menu-icon-open').on('click', function(){
            $('.mobile-menu-icon-open').hide();
            $('.mobile-menu-icon-close').show();
            $('header.masthead').toggleClass('no-bgcolor');
            $('nav ul > li').find('.sub-menu').stop().hide();
            $('.menu-panel').removeClass('halfview');
            $('.sub-menu').removeClass('halfview');
            $('.mastnav').fadeToggle(500);
            $('.mastnav').toggleClass('mastnav-bordered');
        });
        $('.mobile-menu-icon-close').on('click', function(){
            $(this).hide();
            $('.mobile-menu-icon-open').show();
            $('header.masthead').toggleClass('no-bgcolor');
            $('nav ul > li').find('.sub-menu').stop().hide();
            $('.menu-panel').removeClass('halfview');
            $('.sub-menu').removeClass('halfview');
            $('.mastnav').fadeToggle(500);
            $('.mastnav').toggleClass('mastnav-bordered');
        });



        //Sub Menu Trigger
        $('nav ul > li').on('click', function(){
            $('nav ul > li').find('.sub-menu').stop().hide();
            $('.menu-panel').addClass('halfview');
            $('.sub-menu').addClass('halfview');
            $(this).find('.sub-menu').stop().fadeIn(1000);
        });


        //CAROUSELS
        $(".agency-carousel, .horizontal-carousel").owlCarousel({
            autoWidth: false,
            items: 2,
            loop: true,
            nav: false,
            dots: true,
            navText: false,
            addClassActive: true,
            smartSpeed: 1000,
            responsive:{
                0:{
                    items:1
                },
                600:{
                    items:2
                },
                1000:{
                    items:2
                }
            },
            onInitialize:beforeOwlSlide,
            onInitialized:afterOwlSlide,
            onTranslate: beforeOwlSlide,
            onTranslated: afterOwlSlide
        });
        function beforeOwlSlide(){
                    if ( $( ".boxed-caption-anim" ).length ) {
                        $('.boxed-caption-anim').hide();
                        $('.active .boxed-caption-anim').removeClass('anim-slide');
                    }
        }
        function afterOwlSlide(){
                    if ( $( ".boxed-caption-anim" ).length ) {
                    $('.active .boxed-caption-anim').show().addClass('anim-slide');
                    }
        }

        $(".project-carousel").owlCarousel({
            autoWidth: false,
            autoHeight: false,
            items: 1,
            loop: true,
            nav: false,
            dots: true,
            navText: false,
            addClassActive: true,
            smartSpeed: 1000,
            responsive:{
                0:{
                    items:1
                },
                600:{
                    items:1
                },
                1000:{
                    items:1
                }
            }
        });

        $(".clients-carousel").owlCarousel({
            autoWidth: false,
            items: 4,
            loop: true,
            nav: false,
            dots: true,
            navText: false,
            addClassActive: true,
            smartSpeed: 1000,
            autoHeight: false,
            responsive:{
                0:{
                    items:2
                },
                600:{
                    items:3
                },
                1000:{
                    items:4
                }
            }
        });


        $(".testimonial-carousel").owlCarousel({
            autoWidth: false,
            items: 2,
            loop: true,
            nav: false,
            dots: true,
            navText: false,
            addClassActive: true,
            smartSpeed: 1000,
            autoHeight: false,
            responsive:{
                0:{
                    items:1
                },
                600:{
                    items:2
                },
                1000:{
                    items:2
                }
            }
        });

        $(".team-carousel").owlCarousel({
            autoWidth: false,
            items: 3,
            loop: true,
            nav: false,
            dots: true,
            navText: false,
            addClassActive: true,
            smartSpeed: 1000,
            autoHeight: false,
            responsive:{
                0:{
                    items:1
                },
                600:{
                    items:2
                },
                1000:{
                    items:3
                }
            }
        });

        //ISOTOPE
                //ISOTOPE GLOBALS
                var $container1 = $('.works-container');


                //ISOTOPE INIT
                $(window).load(function() {

                   //checking if all images are loaded
                    $container1.imagesLoaded( function() {

                        //init isotope once all images are loaded
                        $container1.isotope({
                            // options
                            itemSelector: '.masonry-item',
                            layoutMode: 'masonry',
                            transitionDuration: '0.8s'
                        });


                        //forcing a perfect masonry layout after initial load
                        setTimeout(function() {
                        $container1.isotope('layout');
                        }, 100);


                        // triggering filtering
                        $('.works-filter li a').on('click', function() {
                            $('.works-filter li a').removeClass('active');
                            $(this).addClass('active');

                            var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
                            $('.works-container').isotope({
                                filter: selector
                            });
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                $container1.isotope('layout');
                            }, 700);
                            return false;
                        });


                        //Isotope ReLayout on Window Resize event.
                        $(window).on('resize', function() {
                            $container1.isotope('layout');
                        });

                        //Isotope ReLayout on device orientation changes
                        window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
                            $container1.isotope('layout');
                        }, false);

                    });

                });

        //Hover Effects
        $('.masonry-item a').on('mouseenter', function() {
                $(this).find('.boxed-caption').slideDown();
         });
        $('.masonry-item a').on('mouseleave', function() {
                $(this).find('.boxed-caption').slideUp();
         });

        //VENOBOX

        $('.venobox').venobox({
            numeratio: true
        });

        //BX SLIDER
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            adaptiveHeight:true
          });
        });


        //MULTI SCROLL

        if ( $( "#multiscroll" ).length ) {

            $('#multiscroll').multiscroll({
                verticalCentered : true,
                scrollingSpeed: 1500,
                easing: 'easeInSine',
                menu: false,
                sectionsColor: [],
                navigation: true,
                navigationPosition: 'right',
                navigationColor: '#000',
                navigationTooltips: [],
                loopBottom: true,
                loopTop: true,
                css3: false,
                paddingTop: 0,
                paddingBottom: 0,
                normalScrollElements: null,
                keyboardScrolling: true,
                touchSensitivity: 5,

                // Custom selectors
                sectionSelector: '.ms-section',
                leftSelector: '.ms-left',
                rightSelector: '.ms-right',

                //events
                onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
                    if ( $( ".boxed-caption-anim" ).length ) {
                        $('.boxed-caption-anim').hide().removeClass('anim-slide');
                    }
                },
                afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
                    if ( $( ".boxed-caption-anim" ).length ) {
                    $('.boxed-caption-anim').show().addClass('anim-slide');
                    }
                },
                afterRender: function(){
                    //re init Venobox after split panel is generated
                    $('.venobox').venobox({
                        numeratio: true
                    });
                    if ( $( ".boxed-caption-anim" ).length ) {
                    $('.boxed-caption-anim').show().addClass('anim-slide');
                    }
                },
                afterResize: function(){},
            });

            $('.ms-section').find('.ms-thumbnail').on('mouseenter', function(){
                $(this).parent().find('.ms-caption').slideDown(1000);
                $(this).addClass('border-wrapped');
            });
            $('.ms-section').on('mouseleave', function(){
                $(this).find('.ms-caption').slideUp(1000);
            });

        }


        //RESPONSIVE VIDEO EMBED
        $(document).ready(function(){
            // Target your .container, .wrapper, .post, etc.
            $(".project-video").fitVids();
        });



        //PARALLAX
        //Initialize Each Parallax Layer  
        function parallaxInit() {
            $.stellar({
                positionProperty: 'transform'
            });
        }

        if (!device.tablet() && !device.mobile()) {

            //Activating Parallax effect if non-mobile device is detected
            $(window).bind('load', function() {
                parallaxInit();
            });


        } else {

            //Dectivate Parallax effect if mobile device is detected (bg image is displayed)
            $('.parallax, .parallax-layer').addClass('no-parallax');

        }   




    });
    // $(function ($)  : ends
})();
//  JSHint wrapper $(function ($)  : ends
```

Comment: I think you use Owl Carousel - Animate Plugin  to make this effect, so you must have some js. You have to remove it. So you arent able to drag your image

Comment: @Sfili_81 thanks for responding. Please guide me how to remove that js code

Comment: .owl-carousel .project-carousel .fullheight one of this classes triggers the event for the carousel, so you have to remove it and modify accordly your html to show only one image

Comment: @Sfili_81 can you help me remotely by accessing my pc? if possible? Because I'm badly stuck here

Comment: It is very simple to do this work. If you have basic html and css skill you can make this work

Comment: yes, I'm trying but it's not sorted out

Comment: @Sfili_81 I've updated the question and added the js code. I hope this can help

Answer (score 1):

You are working with the Owl Carousel JS Plugin. So the easiest thing would be to just remove the JS as @Sfili_81 already commented. The second more complicated way would be to write a custom function in your main.js

In your JS are five sliders which get initialized.
I would suggest, that you make an array, in which are all elements saved, which are initialized like so:

```
var sliderElements = [
        $(".agency-carousel, .horizontal-carousel"),
        $(".project-carousel"),
        $(".clients-carousel"),
        $(".testimonial-carousel"),
        $(".team-carousel")
];
```

Then you can loop through each of them and call a function when they init. Then you can check, if you got more than one item. If not so, you add the class `owl-carousel-pointereventsnone`.

```
for(var i = 0; i < sliderElements.length; i++) {
        sliderElements[i].on('initialize.owl.carousel', function(event) {
                if (!(event.item.index > 1)) {
                        sliderElements[i].addClass('owl-carousel-pointereventsnone');
                }
        });
}
```

The final thing you need to do is to add this class to your CSS with following attribute:

```
.owl-carousel-pointereventsnone {
        pointer-events: none !important;
}
```

This should prevent the user from sliding the images, if there is only one.

If you are sure, that there will only be one image, you also can adjust the items option in the .owlCarousel() function to 1.

Comment: I've updated my question and added the js code. I hope that can help

Comment: add the things i wrote in my answer to your js, then it will work @MurtazaAhmad